# What can slow down a RAID 5 with 3 disks recovery rate to sub-MB speeds?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a RAID 5 on 3 disks 4K aligned (2x WD2001FFSX and 1x WD20EFRX).
One of the disks has failed, and i replaced it with an other WD2001FFSX.

After partitioning it the same way than the other (1 partition getting the entire space, aligned at 2048 sectors), i add it to the raid.

But see by yourself :

```
mick@baloo2:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sde1[0] sdb1[3] sdd1[1]
      3906763776 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.2% (5345880/1953381888) finish=81762.7min speed=396K/sec

unused devices: <none>
mick@baloo2:~$
```

At this speed, this will get about 2 month to accomplish !

Is there anybody here able to point what is wrong in my configuration ?

Here are some useful informations :

```
mick@baloo2:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : 6d208e00:02a3bdac:793d2f47:81af4052
       Name : akela:0
  Creation Time : Sat Apr 16 23:48:38 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 3906763776 (3725.78 GiB 4000.53 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 2505736 sectors
      State : clean
    Device UUID : 840de8ae:f4721e56:71cac3dc:7f9aae2f

    Update Time : Sun May 29 15:31:02 2016
       Checksum : edfdcb1f - correct
     Events : 90414

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$
mick@baloo2:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6d208e00:02a3bdac:793d2f47:81af4052
       Name : akela:0
  Creation Time : Sat Apr 16 23:48:38 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 3906763776 (3725.78 GiB 4000.53 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
      State : clean
    Device UUID : 226eefd7:6da9b123:4240d44b:df2c9dd1

    Update Time : Sun May 29 15:31:02 2016
       Checksum : f5712e5b - correct
     Events : 90414

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$ 
mick@baloo2:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6d208e00:02a3bdac:793d2f47:81af4052
       Name : akela:0
  Creation Time : Sat Apr 16 23:48:38 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 3906763776 (3725.78 GiB 4000.53 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
      State : clean
    Device UUID : 1e381c08:c0a750d5:f85a153b:71d8df29

    Update Time : Sun May 29 15:31:02 2016
       Checksum : 1ec0bcf1 - correct
     Events : 90414

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
mick@baloo2:~$
```

"fdisk -l" give me the following :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc97c3544

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Comment: Two thoughts 1. One of the disks has read/write errors and that's slowing down the rebuild; 2. Your system is in (heavy) use so the rebuild is having to wait for spare IO capacity. #1 would be really bad news. #2 might be normal (but two months does seem excessively slow doesn't it)

Comment: I hope you have a backup because there's a good chance a 2nd drive will fail before the resync is complete....and as @roaima says, it's possible that the slowdown is because a 2nd drive is on the edge of failure.  If I were you, I'd buy 2 x 4+TB drives, set them up as RAID-1 (or btrfs or zfs mirrored-pairs) and rsync everything from the old RAID-5 to that (or restore from backup to the RAID-1 if you have a backup).

Comment: Thanks guys for your ideas. But i'm pretty sure the other drives are OK since I bought them in last april ... Seeing the syslog, it seems there is troubles with the new HDD. I'll go to check cables that I recently changed too. And if no problem at this point, I will try using an external ASUS PCIe SATA I/F. I'll be back with results. And yes, I have some backups, but only for the vital datas ...

Comment: Look in your kernel error log! Don't just feel "pretty sure".

Comment: BTW, you do realise that a 3x2TB raid-5 array has exactly the same capacity as a 2x4TB raid-1 array?  but the raid5 is much slower, especially for writes?  and impossible to recover data from if 2+ drives fail (with raid-1, you can mount each member drive individually and extract what you can from each).  Also, once you've converted to a 2x4TB raid-1, you only have to buy another 2TB disk and you can re-purpose the old raid5 as two 2x2TB raid1 arrays.  i.e. for the price of a 4TB disk and a 2TB disk, you can double your total disk capacity from 4TB to 8TB (4TB + 2TB + 2TB).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you haven't reserved much I/O bandwidth for the rebuild operation.  By default, `md` prefers to use most I/O bandwidth to handle actual requests, with the rebuild having very low priority.  As a side effect, even the slightest I/O to the degraded array will send the rebuild speed plummeting.

You can change this by adjusting `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min` (to change things globally) or `/sys/block/md0/md/sync_speed_min` to change things for a single array.  For example:

echo 6000 > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_speed_min

will provide a minimum rebuild speed of 6000 kb/s, assuming the disks, controller, bus, and processor can all handle it (they should).